# How to auto play a video in background in react using typescript?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-functional-component

I am very new to react and possibly trying to add a autoplay video in one of my components but for some reason it doesn't play if you all can possibly suggest how to do the same.

I have tried using,

export const VideoBg = () =>{
return(



)
};

export const VideoBg = () =>{
return(

Video

)
};

but nothing works please help me out

Comment: hello, you could use this npm package to do that: https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-background-video-player

Answer (score 0):

You can use React refs to control your video elements.

```
export default function App() {
  const videoRef = React.useRef(null);

  function play() {
    videoRef.current.play();
  }

  function pause() {
    videoRef.current.pause();
  }

  return (
    <>
      <video ref={videoRef}>
        <source
          src="https://www.w3schools.com/html/mov_bbb.mp4"
          type="video/mp4"
        />
      </video>
      <button onClick={play}>Start</button>
      <button onClick={pause}>Pause</button>
    </>
  );
}
```

In this example I'm controlling them using buttons, but you can also call these functions from anywhere. If you wanted it to play when the component renders, you'd wrap the function call in a `useEffect` hook.

CodeSandbox:
https://codesandbox.io/s/gracious-mccarthy-benex4